# Substring function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

What is the correct way to check if a string is contained in field in pandas? For example, I have:

```
np.where('DIGITAL_SOURCE' in df['file_name'], 1, 0)
```

But I get the following complaint from Pandas:

> TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

What would be the proper way to do `substr in str` ? I believe the correct answer is using [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) but was having some trouble with the syntax.

Comment: Is [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you can use `.str.contains` (note the `regex=False`, to not treat the string as regular expression):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'file_name': ['DIGITAL_SOURCE', 'Other1', 'Other3']})

df['contains'] = df['file_name'].str.contains('DIGITAL_SOURCE', regex=False).astype(int)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        file_name  contains
0  DIGITAL_SOURCE         1
1          Other1         0
2          Other3         0
```

Comment: @David542 The `astype(int)` will convert `True` and `False` to `1` and `0` respectively

Answer (score 1):

You should do `isin`

```
np.where( df['file_name'].isin(['DIGITAL_SOURCE']), 1, 0)
#df['file_name'].isin(['DIGITAL_SOURCE']).astype(int)
```

Comment: `isin` checks if it is in a list of strings?

Answer (score -1):

you can also apply a lambda such that:

```
 df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if 'DIGITAL_SOURCE' in x['file_name'] else 0, axis=1 )
```

example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"LOCATION":["USA","USA","USA","USA","JAPAN","JAPAN"],"file_name":["DIGITAL","DIGITAL","DIGITAL","DIGITAL","DIGITAL_SOURCE","DIGITAL_SOURCE"]})
 

    LOCATION    file_name
0   USA        DIGITAL
1   USA        DIGITAL
2   USA        DIGITAL
3   USA        DIGITAL
4   JAPAN      DIGITAL_SOURCE
5   JAPAN      DIGITAL_SOURCE


df['new_cl'] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if 'DIGITAL_SOURCE' in x['file_name'] else 0, axis=1 )


    LOCATION    file_name      new_cl
0   USA          DIGITAL        0
1   USA          DIGITAL        0
2   USA          DIGITAL        0
3   USA          DIGITAL        0
4   JAPAN        DIGITAL_SOURCE 1
5   JAPAN        DIGITAL_SOURCE 1
```